# react-router redirect render nothing in protected route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have protected route named `<LoggedRoutes/>` that should redirect and render my `<Onboarding/>` component if the user has not completed his onboarding. But the component is not rendering whereas my `<Login/>` component is rendering if I'm not logged. I don't get why. Note that the redirect is effective because when I try to get to `/edit` for example, I'm redirected to `/onboarding`.

Any ideas why my `<Onboarding/>` component is not rendering ? Thanks in advance! Below is the code :

```
const LoggedRoutes = ({ component: RouteComponent, ...rest }) => {
    const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const onboarding = false;
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={routeProps =>
                !!currentUser && onboarding ? (
                    <RouteComponent {...routeProps} />
                ) : !!currentUser && !onboarding ? (
                    <Redirect to={"/onboarding"} />
                ) : (
                    <Redirect to={"/login"} />
                )
            }
        />
    );
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you check if it throws any error in console also.

Comment: There is no error :/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try this:

```js
const LoggedRoutes = ({ component: RouteComponent, ...rest }) => {
    const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const onboarding = false;
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render = { routeProps => (
                           currentUser && onboarding ? ( <RouteComponent {...routeProps} /> ) :
                           currentUser && !onboarding ? ( <Redirect to={"/onboarding"} /> ) :
                           ( <Redirect to={"/login"} /> )
                    )}
        />
    );
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I already tried and there is no difference

Comment: can you share your code on stackblitz? so that I can see it in action. @r10d

Answer (score 0):

With  onboarding hardcoded to `false`, The below statement turns out to be like this

```
currentUser && false  ? ( <RouteComponent {...routeProps} /> ) :
currentUser && true ? ( <Redirect to={"/onboarding"} /> ) :
                             ( <Redirect to={"/login"} /> )
```

and then,

```
false  ? ( <RouteComponent {...routeProps} /> ) :
currentUser  ? ( <Redirect to={"/onboarding"} /> ) :
                             ( <Redirect to={"/login"} /> )
```

So it only depends on `currentUser` value. Check whether its value is null/undefined.